# Microtype, MinionPro, and TeXLive 2016

Tags: pdftex, microtype, texlive-2016

Since moving to TeXLive 2016 I'm unable to use `microtype` with the `MinionPro` package. Here's a MWE, which compiles just fine with TeXLive 2015:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

When I try running this through `pdfLaTeX`, I get a font expansion error:

```
pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
Check the TeX log file for more information
```

I suspect the problem is due to an out-of-date `microtype` configuration file. If so, what's the easiest way to fix that? (Getting Minion Pro to work with LaTeX was quite a headache, so if possible I'm looking for a way to avoid having to do it all over again.)

(If not, what else could be going on?)

Comment: Remove microtype, compile with pdflatex and then show what fonts this is using (see the list at the end of the log-file).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but there seems to be a problem with my font files and TeXLive 2016. When I run compile without `microtype` I also get an error message: `Font MinionPro-Regular-osf-ot1--base at 545 not found`

Comment: What should I be looking for in the log file?

Comment: In general this means that you haven't enable the map file. Does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=MinionPro.map}` to your document?

Comment: Yes! That works fine, both with and without `microtype`. Is there a way to fix this other than adding that bit of code to every file? (Also, why doesn't this problem arise with TeXLive 2015?)

Comment: Normally you should be able to add the map-file permantly with `updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map`.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that. I tried doing that, but I get an error message (can't find the map file). I think my fonts are installed in my local `texmf` tree. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: OK, just running `updmap` seems to have worked.