# Installation of MinionPro: not scalable font?

Tags: ubuntu, microtype, minionpro

I have installed Minion Pro on my system following [this description](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts/). I managed to compile the simple test document without a problem, but once I compile the following I get

> ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
> fonts.

When I do small variations on the document (I dont understand how to reproduce at the moment), I alternatively also get the following error:

```
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OML+MinionPro-TOsF on i
nput line 15.
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/OMLMinionPro-TOsF.fd
File: OMLMinionPro-TOsF.fd 2005/01/23 v2.0 font definitions for OML/MinionPro-T
OsF.
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro-FontDef.sty
File: MinionPro-FontDef.sty 2007/02/01 v2.2 font definition macros
)) [1
{/home/x/.texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./tes
t2.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
6639 strings out of 483140
105390 string characters out of 5965151
315287 words of memory out of 5000000
21601 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
627487 words of font info for 76 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
45i,4n,59p,411b,398s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/MnSymbol/MnSymbolD.enc}
!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file MinionPro-It-Base-ae): Font MinionPro-It
-Base-ae at 655 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342528/microtype-minionpro-and-texlive-2016), the inclusion of the following helps:

```
\pdfmapfile{=MinionPro.map}
```

If I include it, I can compile the document without a problem. So it appears that I just have to install the mapping:

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map
```

Notice that I already the following in `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg':

```
MixedMap MnSymbol.map
Map MinionPro.map
```

perhaps this is why running the `updmap-sys` command doesnt change anything:

```
$ updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

As a side note, all the commands from the tutorial wouldn't work in a vanilla Ubuntu installation, I had to `sudo` most of them.

Comment: `/home/x/.texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` is a local pdftex.map which shadows everything you do with updmap-sys, perhaps you did run updmap at some time. Remove this local map file and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This helped. If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home/x/.texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` is a local `pdftex.map` which shadows everything you do with `updmap-sys` (perhaps you did run `updmap` at some time).

Remove this local map file and try again

Comment: I guess this is the 227th case of somebody running udpmap, wondering, why udpmap-sys afterwards doesn't work, comming to tex.SE to ask and get your answer as above. That said, why not change texlive: require users to read a warning before running updmap? »If you run updmap, any attempt to run updmap-sys won't effect changes in future. Running updmap instead of updmap-sys is a common beginners mistake. Do you want to proceed, though? (y/n)«

Comment: @KeksDose try `updmap` in a current texlive 2020 ...

Comment: Ahh! Very well.